# Characteristic $0$ non-algebraically closed field which does not admit an ordering

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, order-theory

Are there any characteristic $0$ fields which are not algebraically closed and do not admit an ordering making them an ordered field?

Comment: Fields which admit an ordering making them an ordered field are exactly those where $-1$ is not a sum of squares; see [formally real fields][1]


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\mathbb{C}(X)$ (the field of rational functions over the complex numbers). This field has characteristic zero and does not admit an ordering, otherwise also $\mathbb{C}$ would. It is not algebraically closed as the polynomial $T^2 - X\in \mathbb{C}(X)[T]$ has no zero in $\mathbb{C}(X)$ (the square root is not a rational function).

Comment: The other two answers made me slap my forehead because I missed them -- this one surprises me more, so the answer points are yours. Thanks to all who answered!

Answer (score 7):

Yes: the field $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ . It has an element whose square is $-1$ and that's enough to prove it.

Answer (score 7):

How about $\mathbb{Q}[i]$?

Not algebraically closed for similar reasons to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Not an ordered field for similar reasons to $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3):

Also, for $p \in \mathbb{N}$ prime, $\mathbb{Q}_p$, the $p$-adic numbers, are an unorderable field of characteristic zero that is not algebraically closed.  (Perhaps also interesting, their algebraic closure is a field extension of infinite degree, unlike $\mathbb{R}$.)